# The div is already set as displayed, i didn't get fade in effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some div in my page. when i click some link in that page, i want to display the corresponding div in fade in effect. My problem is that the div is already set as `display='block'`, i didn't get fade in effect. Can any one help

Answer (score 0):

Well, you'd need to make sure the div is **not** set as `display: block` and instead set as `display: none`.

Then when you fade in, div will automatically have `display: block` because divs are block level elements.